# How to determine variable importance for feature selection with glmnet?

Tags: r, feature-selection, regularization, glmnet

Sorry about this question because it has already been asked but I am really lost to find **how to determine the variable importance in glmnet??**

Variable importance here refer to, for instance, the Random Forest [`varImp()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-88/topics/varImp) function, whit which you can see which feature drives the most the target attribute.

With the regularization, looking only at the unstandardized coefficients doesn't help and I am not sure I can access the standardized coefficient from the `glmnet` object.

I tried:

```
lasso$beta
```

Which returns:

```
35 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                           s0
(Intercept)      .           
samp_eff         1.414232e-01
B1_cv            .           
B2_cv            .           
B3_cv           -7.529949e-04
B4_cv           -2.339615e-03
B5_cv           -4.571802e-04
B6_cv            .           
B7_cv            3.745669e-04
B10_cv          -5.131828e-02
ndvi_cv          .           
ndvi_water_cv    .           
ndwi_cv          .           
evi_cv           1.293439e-03
B1_rao           .           
B2_rao           .           
B3_rao           .           
B4_rao          -3.316356e+00
B5_rao          -3.015584e+00
B6_rao           .           
B7_rao           1.437572e-03
ndwi_rao         .           
ndvi_rao        -7.407094e-04
min_alt          3.175029e-04
max_alt          .           
av_alt          -2.147137e-04
diff_alt         .           
cluster_corine2  1.769418e-02
cluster_corine3  4.910332e-03
cluster_corine4  2.250217e-02
corine_1        -8.217931e-05
corine_2         2.547073e-02
corine_3         1.818796e-02
corine_4         .           
corine_5         4.997473e-02
```

If I order these coefficients, can I consider them as the importance order? I am not sure about the meaning of the `lass$beta` output.

As a second step, I tried to use the `varImp()` function on my lasso regularization as follow:

```
varImp(lasso, lambda = cv_lasso$lambda.min)
```

Which returns:

```
Overall
1  3.749767e+00
2  0.000000e+00
3  1.414232e-01
4  0.000000e+00
5  0.000000e+00
6  7.529949e-04
7  2.339615e-03
8  4.571802e-04
9  0.000000e+00
10 3.745669e-04
11 5.131828e-02
12 0.000000e+00
13 0.000000e+00
14 0.000000e+00
15 1.293439e-03
16 0.000000e+00
17 0.000000e+00
18 0.000000e+00
19 3.316356e+00
20 3.015584e+00
21 0.000000e+00
22 1.437572e-03
23 0.000000e+00
24 7.407094e-04
25 3.175029e-04
26 0.000000e+00
27 2.147137e-04
28 0.000000e+00
29 1.769418e-02
30 4.910332e-03
31 2.250217e-02
32 8.217931e-05
33 2.547073e-02
34 1.818796e-02
35 0.000000e+00
36 4.997473e-02
```

The thing is that I don't know **1)** if they are the standardized coefficient and **2)** to which feature correspond each coefficient (there's no row names)

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your predictor variables $X$ should all be on the same scale when doing a lasso regression. Having variables on wildly different scales can lead the penalization process to consider some variables more than others. See [*Introduction to Statistical Learning*, page 217](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5ff2adbe3fe4fe33db902812/t/6062a083acbfe82c7195b27d/1617076404560/ISLR%2BSeventh%2BPrinting.pdf).

This also means that your coefficients are able to be directly compared to one another, since all the predictors are on the same scale. That means you can just look at the coefficients to determine variable importance. I simulate data below—all on wildly different scales—before z-scoring them all to be on the same scale. Then I use the `broom::tidy` function to get the row names AND coefficients. Then I sort descending by the absolute value of the coefficient to see which are most influential in the model.

```
# generate fake data -----------------------------------------------------------
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1839)
n <- 1000

dat <- tibble(
  x1 = runif(n, -10, 10),
  x2 = rbinom(n, 1, .3),
  x3 = rbinom(n, 1, .5),
  x4 = rnorm(n),
  x5 = rnorm(n, 5, 30),
  x6 = rgamma(n, .5),
  y = .5 * x1 + 3 * x4 + -7 * x6 + rnorm(n)
)

# note that not all predictors are on the same scale:
map(1:6, function(i) c(summary(dat[[i]]), "St. Dev." = sd(dat[[i]])))

# you want everything on the same scale:
dat <- dat %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("x"), function(i) as.vector(scale(i))))

# now, it's fixed. they've all got a mean of 0 and sd of 1
map(1:6, function(i) c(summary(dat[[i]]), "St. Dev." = sd(dat[[i]])))

# run a lasso ------------------------------------------------------------------
library(glmnet)
lambda <- cv.glmnet(as.matrix(dat[1:6]), dat[[7]])$lambda.1se
mod <- glmnet(as.matrix(dat[1:6]), dat[[7]], lambda = lambda)

# use the broom package to get the row names you want:
broom::tidy(mod) %>% 
  slice(-1) %>%  # drop the intercept
  arrange(desc(abs(estimate)))
```

This should give you a tidy data frame of your results, sorted from most important to least important. It drops all the zero coefficients out.

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  term   step estimate lambda dev.ratio
  <chr> <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>
1 x6        1    -5.23  0.133     0.978
2 x4        1     2.82  0.133     0.978
3 x1        1     2.68  0.133     0.978
```

The `term` refers to each variable, and the `estimate` refers to the coefficient—which is a measure of variable importance for this model.

Comment: What a very complete answer Mark, thanks a lot!! So your idea is to standardize them before making the regularization. I read somewhere that the `glmnet` function does so during the process but then it is impossible to access the standardized coefficients. I'll do this on my side :) Cheers!

Comment: Yeah, honestly `glmnet` does some standardization stuff I don't fully understand—it's a little opaque, in my opinion. It's weird because it's the package everyone uses, but they formulate the LASSO just ever so slightly different from how books teach it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Lasso/Ridge/Elastic Nets are linear models, so there is no need for "importance".
If you see that `min_alt` variable has a $\beta$ of `3.175029e-04`, that means that an increase in unit of `min_alt` increases the expected value of the dependant variable, your Y, by `3.175029e-04`.

As you can see then, if you want to rank variables by "importance" you shouldn't just compare $\beta$ but look at the domain of each $X$ (and therefore, what it means to increase it by "one" unit)

Comment: Also, if you are interested in the "varImp" in caret for linear model, it will return "absolute value of the t-statistic" which is your beta divided by its standard error. 
I am not super-sure how you'd use them for ranking; usually you extract them for p-value computations but I am not sure how reliable p-value testing is for regularized regressions like the ones you are using

Comment: As you said, at first I was looking at the coefficients to see the impact on the target attribute. And I wanted to select the features by saying "the highest absolute value is the most important feature etc". The thing is that I can work only on the standardized coefficients and I am not sure if the outputs of the functions that I used are standardized (and actually I think they are not)

Comment: Notice that Glmnet is already doing feature selection for you, so in a way you are already looking at what glmnet and cross-validation thought was the "best" set of features. 
If, for whatever reason, you want to choose even fewer features, your best bet is to use the original `glmnet` library as it will generate a large set of betas for many different value of the penalty parameter and you can pick a high penalty result which will have only few non-zero betas. Of course your fit quality will decline. All `caret` does is picking the penalty parameter that cross-validates better.

Comment: Thanks a lot @CarrKnight. Indeed, I could use the regularized model to make my predictions but I wanted to compare the variable importance of the regularization with the variable importance of the Random Forest (for a model comparison problem)